# Changing style of element in Vue depending on true/false from element in api

Tags: vue.js

How to change style(color) of paragraph in Vue if element (boolean) from api returns true

```
<p v-if="discount = false">Discount</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the class binding `v-bind:class` or shorthand `:class` to accomplish this.
Same goes for `v-bind:style | :style`

Example:

```
<p :class="{ 'someClass': discount, 'someotherClass': !discount }">Discount</p>
```

Resource: [VueJS Class and Style binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Comment: Thank you very much